# Can anyone please tell me how is Kernel Programming done in Linux, as Windows DDK in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, linux-kernel

I am aware of windows kernel but new to linux kernel. I just need to know how its done in linux, i.e. the program development.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [there (free-electrons.com)](http://free-electrons.com/docs/), it's a good informations source for kernel developement. (specialized in embedded linux, but most of the docs are available for standard development)

You have also the classical [Linux Devices Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), which is very complete and detailled.

And last but not least, the [Linux kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/).

Comment: thnx for a quick reply, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not have a stable kernel API. This is by design, so you should generally avoid writing kernel code if you can; it is unlikely to remain source-compatible indefinitely, and will definitely NOT be binary-compatible, even between minor releases.

This is less-or-more true for vendor kernels; Redhat etc DO maintain source & binary kernel compatibility between major revisions.

More work is gradually being done in the kernel to reduce the amount of kernel-code required to carry out various tasks, such as driver development (for example, USB drivers can typically be done in userspace with libusb), filesystem development (FUSE) and network filtering (NFQUEUE). However, there are still some cases where you need to; in particular, block devices still need to be in the kernel to be able to be usefully used for boot devices and swap.